# WorkerRole in Azure Cloud Service net connection

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, hyper-v, azure-cloud-services

This afternoon I have uploaded my WorkerRole in Cloud Service on Azure, this service run on VM with Windows Server 2012. I have realized that WorkerRole can't get query from Databases (BigQuery, TSQL). When I have read the service log in VM I have seen the following error:

> The VM and host networking components failed to negotiate protocol version '5.0'

I think that Hyper-V-vsc has something to do. Anybody knows what happens?

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 0):

First thing I could check is to make sure the databases you are trying to connect too have whitelisted the VIP for the cloud service you're connecting from. And if you haven't already, remote into an instance of the worker and try reaching the DB's using a thin a client UI as you can.

In my experience, these issues are usually on the db end. Azure doesn't do much with blocking outbound connections. Those that fail are usually more a matter of protocol (UDP multicast for example).

Comment: So, How I check if service cloud is in Azure Database whitelist? Is strange because i can't connect to google bigquery and azure database

Comment: My Azure SQL firewall allow azure services.

Comment: Ok, have you checked a tracert to see where the connection if failing? Or if this is a DNS related issue?

Comment: I've tried to ping google.com inside VM, the dns resolution is ok but  I don't recieve data.

Comment: Not sure what else to recommend other then opening a support ticket. I haven't run into this type of issue. My last ditch attempt would be to double check the firwall configuration on the VM and make sure there's nothing there blocking things.

Comment: I could fix it. Using Remote Debugger I could debug my code in cloud service. My problem was in one method that throw an Exception. However, I had do it more steps to running cloud service correctly.

Comment: I'm very disgusted because there are multiple errors that Azure Emulator doesn't show, but these errors happens in the cloud. This cause, increases the difficulty of  code

Comment: When dealing with cloud applications, proper instrumentation and logging are key. Imagine having 100 instances of that app running and not knowing precisely what's going wrong with one. While remote debugging is an option, its still no substitute for proper instrumentation when dealing with production scenarios.